# How to check how and when a malicious file was uploaded on Linux?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, security

I have an issue with some malicious files that keep showing up in my WordPress folders and I have no idea where are they coming from. Most of my plugins are popular ones, I have updated all plugins and word press too.

I just removed the malicious files that were used to send spam emails but just a few hours later, a new file showed up in a random folder.

My question is: how can I find how it was uploaded? I checked: cPanel logs, FTP logs in /var/logs/messages and access logs from WHM for my domain.

None of them show any occurrence of that specific filename.

Any idea?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Those files are probably uploaded by malware script. You should check your php / apache access logs and look for files you don't recognize. I have seen hackers upload scripts that can look like it's part of wordpress core, but in fact, this files give them access to do whatever they want.

Simple steps to follow. If one fails, proceeed to next one.

1. Go through your apache / php logs
2. Check your home folder / uploads for any *.php / *.js (or any other irregular) files.
3. Check if there is any additional user in wordpress admin panel.
4. Remove all plugins and make a clean install, not just update them.
5. Make a clean wordpress installation. (also from source, not just update).

Make sure that you change all your passwords which were stored in wp-config.php, because hackers had access to it, and they can get into your database and hack your website again.

Comment: I know. I even found the script, but I don't know how they managed to upload it.

Comment: and if I remove it, they keep reuploading it

Comment: I've seen them put this scripts inside core files of wordpress. It seems like nothing has changed, but if you go to specific page with given param, you are accessing their script.